# how to solve flutter audio player getter name error

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

trying to follow a flutter tutorial and its packages documentation but i have no idea why it isnt working. to be precise its the audio players package. and when i run it i get this error message

```
/D:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/audioplayers_platform_interface-1.0.0/lib/api/audio_context_config.dart:242:28: Error: The getter 'name' isn't defined for the class 'AVAudioSessionCategory'.
 - 'AVAudioSessionCategory' is from 'package:audioplayers_platform_interface/api/audio_context_config.dart' ('/D:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/audioplayers_platform_interface-1.0.0/lib/api/audio_context_config.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'name'.
      'category': category.name,
                           ^^^^
/D:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/audioplayers_platform_interface-1.0.0/lib/api/audio_context_config.dart:243:39: Error: The getter 'name' isn't defined for the class 'AVAudioSessionOptions'.
 - 'AVAudioSessionOptions' is from 'package:audioplayers_platform_interface/api/audio_context_config.dart' ('/D:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/audioplayers_platform_interface-1.0.0/lib/api/audio_context_config.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'name'.
      'options': options.map((e) => e.name).toList(),
```

any advice?

Comment: Looks like it's an open issue... https://github.com/bluefireteam/audioplayers/issues/1163

Comment: The only way I could get it to run was to downgrade the package version in pubspec.yaml to audioplayers: 0.20.1